# How to update a chatMessage on quickblox android

Tags: java, android, quickblox, quickblox-android

Hi so I've just started using quickblox for android and I find it confusing that when updating a chatMesage I'm only limited to editing the text. Here is the code provided:

```
QBMessageUpdateBuilder messageUpdateBuilder = new QBMessageUpdateBuilder();
messageUpdateBuilder.updateText("Updated message body string");

// If you want to mark message as Delivered or Read on the server
//messageUpdateBuilder.markDelivered();
//messageUpdateBuilder.markRead();

QBRestChatService.updateMessage(message.getId(), message.getDialogId(), messageUpdateBuilder).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override 
public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

}
});
```

I however have properties that I had set when creating the message using chatmessage.setProperty("myproperty", value) and I would like to update this at a later time yet I have found no method to facilitate this. Could there be a hack for doing so? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is Nikolay from QuickBlox support.

Unfortunately, there are no other options to update messages in our SDK.

You can change the messageand also use the updateMessage() method to mark message as delivered or read on the server.

You may find our Custom objects functionality useful to build a custom logic:
https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/android-custom-objects

Answer (score -1):

Hello mr Nikolay Zolotarov,

I think you are wrong, SDK has update message method https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/android-chat-messaging#update-message but you can't update custom parameters

Comment: This looks more like a comment to the other answer rather than a new answer.